# Can a variable derived using count data be used to model zero inflation in a Zero-Inflation Poisson model?

Tags: r, count-data, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

Say I have a zero-inflation Poisson model that is count ~ var1. My count data is inflated by zeros because count is the number of symptoms of a particular disorder.

If count > 5, and those symptoms are impairing, the participant has the disorder. If count <= 5 (or symptoms not impairing) they don't. The dataset has many healthy controls (count = 0), a few people with the disorder, and some in between.

I'm currently using var1 both to model the counts and the zero-inflation model. My research question is whether var1 affects symptom count (and how). Would it make sense to use a binary variable for the presence of the disorder for the zero-inflation model instead? In other words, if using the pscl package in R, count ~ var1 | hasDisorder ?

I'm not sure if it'd be incorrect, since that binary variable is somewhat related to the counts.

Thanks!

Comment: Is hasDisorder defined as "No" if count < 5 and "Yes" if count >= 5? If so, including hasDisorder overshadows any other covariate added to the model. It seems a circular analysis. The covariate var1 would  only matters if it explains the variability for counts between 0 and 5. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Sort of. hasDisorder can only be "Yes" if enough of the counts are impairing. For example, even if count == 6, hasDisorder would only be "Yes" if 5 of those are impairing (we don't have the impairment status in the dataset). So, although someone with count < 5 cannot be hasDisorder=Yes, not all count>=5 will be hasDisorder=Yes. I was hoping var1 could still be useful in explaining variability in counts above 5 as well.